# Instagram messaging webhook, Recipient ID is incorrect

Tags: instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

When I connect any instagram account to my application, It provides an object that contains "connected_instagram_account" ID. This information is saved into my database along with the access token.
When the connected instagram page receive a message, I get a webhook into my application. The issue is that the "recipient id" in that webhook is not equal to the "connect_instagram_account" id.

Answer (score 0):

if you are in development mode, facebook will send a fake recipient id to you. the only way to make it work is this:
give that user the administrator role in your facebook app